# How does Rsync behave when sychronizing?

Tags: linux, rsync

Say I have a file in a directory mysite/a.php on machine A and machine B. The files will not have any difference initially.

On machine A if a.php is changed and then when a sync is done from machine B to A, will a.php have the change or will it be overwritten? What about directories?

Comment: Did you have any particular flags that you wanted to use?

Answer (score 0):

Rsync synchronizes only in one direction.

If you sync from B to A, then the content in A is overwritten (and vice versa). Basically you should to select one master machine and make all changes there.

If changes have to be done at both machines, then you'll need bidirectional synchronization. [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) is a good program for that purpose.